# not able to get div with border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a simple css border effect with proper padding. Trying to make it responsive without using bootstrap.

I just have one font and border around it  and arrows between two div but I am not getting it 
code:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
.work {
  float: left;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.work:before {
  content: '\f178';
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -11px;
  top: 44%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST7</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

link to codepen: https://codepen.io/rahulv/pen/BRwjEd

what I am trying to acheive is I dont get padding between two boxes also I want arrow between them .. its like test1 -> test2 -> test3..

Comment: In border, you need to define the style (dotted, dashed, solid). Update your code to `border: solid 4px black;` If you want to separate the divs themself, set a margin. i.e `margin: 0 20px.`

Comment: @VegaStudios Thanks for pointing that out but now I dont get padding between two boxes also I want arrow between them .. its like test1 -> test2 -> test3..

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/wdrGMy

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes.. need just one edit <i> should be right above the text TEST and arrow(->) should be between two boxes... it like steps test1 then test2 like wise

Comment: @sam you should draw a picture or something if you want someone here to do those things for you. It isn't clear from your post. "padding between two boxes" - I think you mean margin?

Comment: @sam updated the pen - https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/wdrGMy that what you're going for?

Comment: yup.. works for me and thanks for helping me understand CSS

Comment: @sam no sweat. submitted as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelCoker when I am applying it to my project I don't see work:before is being called

Comment: @sam i don't understand. it's in your codepen in the code and I see the icon. what's the problem?

Comment: @MichaelCoker  ya thats stange: I copy pasted the code but :before suedo is not applying.. any help on how to debug?

Comment: If you have the font awesome stylesheet on the page, nope. Can you send me a link? If I can't see it all I can do is guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the border style property which is required. Also you need `position: relative;` on `.work` to make the absolutely positioned psuedo element work, and the font-awesome font-family. Text-align: center for icons...

Check out full example:

```css
.work{
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.work:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.work:not(:last-of-type):before {
    content: '\f178';
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -22px;
    top: 41%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
<div class="work">
<i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
<h4>TEST1</h4>
</div>
  
  <div class="work">
<i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
<h4>TEST2</h4>
    
</div>
  
  <div class="work">
<i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
<h4>TEST3</h4>
</div>
  <div class="work">
<i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
<h4>TEST4</h4>
</div>
  <div class="work">
<i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
<h4>TEST5</h4>
</div>
  <div class="work">
<i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
<h4>TEST6</h4>
</div>
  <div class="work">
<i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
<h4>TEST7</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but now I dont get padding between two boxes also I want arrow between them   .. its like test1 -> test2 -> test3...

Comment: You need position relative on parent for absolute positioned arrow to work. And you must mean margin between the boxes. I edited answer

Comment: awesome but I also edited it a little more to get tyhe <i> tag in middle tight above the TEST word .work i{
  color:blue;
  padding-left:17%;
  padding-top:10%;
}  but this increases the box size

Comment: If you look at my example again, i just put text-align: center on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following changes

```
.work:before {
    content: '\f178';
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -23px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

and

```
 .work:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: 20px;
 }
```

Here is working final demo

http://codepen.io/sajiddesigner/pen/EmwKvj

Comment: You literally just copied my old answer... I'm sure you used the selector .work:not(:last-of-type) and the exact same amount of margin left...

Comment: Yes bro.. i did because i did'nt noticed your comment and went to codepen provided by sam and changed values there.. and adding margin is not a trick. actual thing is using top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. My b

Answer (score 0):

To put the font awesome arrow outside of the right of the parent, use `right: 0;` to move it to the right side, then push it outside of the parent with `translateX()`.

To have the puzzle piece right above the text, remove the `margin` (or just `margin-top`) from the text.

To have space between the boxes, you need a right `margin`.

```css
.work {
  float: left;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.work:before {
  content: '\f178';
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(150%);
  top: 50%; right: 0;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="work">
    <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <h4>TEST7</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the type of border

try using this:

```
border: 4px black solid;
```

Comment: This isn't a complete answer. It only addresses part of the problem.